# What do the parameters mean in scull's proc read implementation?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

In LDD3's (Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition book) `scullpipe`, what do the parameters in `static int scull_read_p_mem(char *buf, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data)` mean? Specifically, I don't understand the difference between `start`, `page`, and `offset`.

There are a number of questions I have regarding the actual implementation itself (which can be found below):

```
struct scull_pipe {
        wait_queue_head_t inq, outq;       /* read and write queues */
        char *buffer, *end;                /* begin of buf, end of buf */
        int buffersize;                    /* used in pointer arithmetic */
        char *rp, *wp;                     /* where to read, where to write */
        int nreaders, nwriters;            /* number of openings for r/w */
        struct fasync_struct *async_queue; /* asynchronous readers */
        struct semaphore sem;              /* mutual exclusion semaphore */
        struct cdev cdev;                  /* Char device structure */
};

int scull_p_nr_devs;            /* the number of scull_pipe devices */
scull_pipe *scull_p_devices;    /* scull_pipe devices to be malloc'ed */

/* ...... */

/* our proc read implementation */
static int scull_read_p_mem(char *buf, char **start, off_t offset, int count,
        int *eof, void *data)
{
    int i, len;
    struct scull_pipe *p;

#define LIMIT (PAGE_SIZE-200)   /* don't print any more after this size */
    *start = buf;
    len = sprintf(buf, "Default buffersize is %i\n", scull_p_buffer);
    for(i = 0; i < scull_p_nr_devs && len <= LIMIT; i++) {
        p = &scull_p_devices[i];
        if (down_interruptible(&p->sem))
            return -ERESTARTSYS;
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "\nDevice %i: %p\n", i, p);
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "   Buffer: %p to %p (%i bytes)\n", 
                                    p->buffer, p->end, p->buffersize);
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "   rp %p   wp %p\n", p->rp, p->wp);
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "   readers %i   writers %i\n", 
                                    p->nreaders, p->nwriters);
        up(&p->sem);
        scullp_proc_offset(buf, start, &offset, &len);
    }
    *eof = (len <= LIMIT);
    return len;
}


static void scullp_proc_offset(char *buf, char **start, off_t *offset, int *len)
{
    /* QUESTION: what does this function do? */
    if (*offset == 0)
        return;
    if (*offset >= *len) {
        *offset -= *len;    /* QUESTION: what is the purpose of this? */
        *len = 0;
    }
    else {
        *start = buf + *offset; /* QUESTION: why do you need to change "start"? */
        *offset = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [scull_read_p_mem](https://github.com/starpos/scull/blob/master/scull/pipe.c#L280) is used to create a proc entry [here](https://github.com/starpos/scull/blob/master/scull/pipe.c#L370) using [create_proc_read_entry](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.0/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h#L160) function. A 5 minut google search gave [this page](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2010/12/creating-proc-entry-2.html) which explain the parameters in the function pointer passed to `create_proc_read_entry` function. With fixed formatting is sais:

> Arguments:
>   *buf : The kernel allocates a page of memory to any process that attempts to read a proc entry. The page pointer points to that buffer
>   of memory into which the data is written.
>   **start: This pointer is used when the reading of the proc file should not start from the beginning of the file but from a certain offset. For small reads this is generally set to NULL.
>   off : The offset from the beginning of the file where the file pointer currently points to
>   count : The number of bytes of data to be read
>   data : The data passed from the create_read_proc_entry function call.
>   eof: is set to 1 to indicate end of file

But after a while i've also found some docs in [kenel fs/proc/generic.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.0/source/fs/proc/generic.c#L76). It's a bit long, but I think it's the only source to sum up the `start` parameter:

```
        /*
         * How to be a proc read function
         * ------------------------------
         * Prototype:
         *    int f(char *buffer, char **start, off_t offset,
         *          int count, int *peof, void *dat)
         *
         * Assume that the buffer is "count" bytes in size.
         *
         * If you know you have supplied all the data you
         * have, set *peof.
         *
         * You have three ways to return data:
         * 0) Leave *start = NULL.  (This is the default.)
         *    Put the data of the requested offset at that
         *    offset within the buffer.  Return the number (n)
         *    of bytes there are from the beginning of the
         *    buffer up to the last byte of data.  If the
         *    number of supplied bytes (= n - offset) is 
         *    greater than zero and you didn't signal eof
         *    and the reader is prepared to take more data
         *    you will be called again with the requested
         *    offset advanced by the number of bytes 
         *    absorbed.  This interface is useful for files
         *    no larger than the buffer.
         * 1) Set *start = an unsigned long value less than
         *    the buffer address but greater than zero.
         *    Put the data of the requested offset at the
         *    beginning of the buffer.  Return the number of
         *    bytes of data placed there.  If this number is
         *    greater than zero and you didn't signal eof
         *    and the reader is prepared to take more data
         *    you will be called again with the requested
         *    offset advanced by *start.  This interface is
         *    useful when you have a large file consisting
         *    of a series of blocks which you want to count
         *    and return as wholes.
         *    (Hack by Paul.Russell@rustcorp.com.au)
         * 2) Set *start = an address within the buffer.
         *    Put the data of the requested offset at *start.
         *    Return the number of bytes of data placed there.
         *    If this number is greater than zero and you
         *    didn't signal eof and the reader is prepared to
         *    take more data you will be called again with the
         *    requested offset advanced by the number of bytes
         *    absorbed.
         */
```

We can [see](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.0/source/fs/proc/generic.c#L175) the `start` used later inside `copy_to_user` - the parameter is used to optimize `proc` entry reads on biiiig files. The user can pass the `count` variable really small, but you have biig file to read. So you return the size of that file from the proc read function with a `*start` parameter, that says how many bytes are there to read. That way kernel can even pass `count=0`, but the proc_read function can return like `5000` with a valid `*start` address, it will be later used in `copy_to_user` call to speed up the read.

So:

> what do the parameters in static int scull_read_p_mem(char *buf, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data) mean?

- `buf` - destination buffer to copy the result to
- `start` - the magic pointer explained in the comment above used to speed up proc reading.
- `offset` - offset in the file to read from
- `count` - count of bytes to read
- `eof` - a pointer to int, that need to be set to nonzero, in case the whole file is read
- `data` - user context, passed as the last parameter in the `create_proc_entry` function.

> There are a number of questions I have regarding the actual implementation itself (which can be found below):

The `scullp_proc_offset` manipulates the `len` offset inside the `buf` buffer. If `offset != 0`, then the `scull_read_p_mem` needs not to read from the first byte, but some byte `offset`. Because it is lazily written, then `snprintf` calls execute anyways, you need "kind of shift" the buffer.

`what does this function do?` - Actually I see it is a funny way of counting how many bytes were/need to be copied to the user.

`what is the purpose of this?` - No idea. Looks buggy tho, as `*offset` will become negative. The comment above the function `/* FIXME this should use seq_file */` says there is something left to fix. I think the ides is return exactly information about one `scull_p_devices[i]` in one call.

`why do you need to change "start"?` - which comes to this. If `*offset` is different then 0 and if we have some bytes to read, we should return a pointer to `buf + offset`, to let kernel know from where to read. Note, that `*start = buf` was initialized already, so the kernel will do `copy_to_user(... *start, len)`.

Comment: What is the difference in functionality between (0) and (2)? I don't really see how those two differ from each other.

Comment: Look at kernel source, below is the `copy_to_user` call. It has the `start < page ? page : start`. Imagine kernel uses a small buffer like `10`, but it needs to read `10000` bytes. It would take `1000` calls, each would return `10` bytes read and `*start=NULL`. Now, with the `start` functionality, your proc reading function can just ignore `count` and just return `10000` with `*start=some_valid_address`. Kernel will then call `copy_to_user(destination, *start, 10000)` copy the bytes in a _single call_, not in 1000 calls.

Answer (score 0):

The `buf` points to the base of a memory page, where the read result should be stored.

The `offset` suggests where the read should begin in the virtual file.

`start` as a return value can mean a few thing:

1. `if start == null`, we have write result to buf + offset
2. `if start == some int <` buf address, we have write result to buf
3. `if start == some` address within buf, we have write result to start

And the function should be interpreted as following.

```
// context:
// 1. We have set start to be the beginning of buf
//     *start = buf;
// 2. We have fill some string into the buf and increment len
static void scullp_proc_offset(char *buf, char **start, off_t *offset, int *len)
{
    // If offset is zero, we are filling a new buf.
    // (Or we have finished catching up as shown below)
    // We can continue to do so until we reach buf size
    if (*offset == 0)
        return;

    // Otherwise, we have some offset to catch up to.
    if (*offset >= *len) {
        // The offset might be still ahead given we have filled len.
        // So, we reduce offset(meaning that we have done some catch up)
        // and reset len(because we are still working on old data)
        *offset -= *len;
        *len = 0;
    }
    else {
        // Or, the offset might be already behind us
        // So, we set start to indicate that the write starts from this address
        // (case 2 in fs/proc/generic.c#L76)
        // and reset offset (meaning that we are done with catching up)
        *start = buf + *offset;
        *offset = 0;
        // this part might lack the handling of len
        // but it might be true if the structure is the same between two calls.
    }
}
```

In conclusion, the author uses this function to so that the write always starts at `buf`, but only counts len after catching up with previous offset.